# Copy Used Range from Sheet1 and paste into Sheet3

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to make a code which copies the `UsedRange` from `Sheet1` and Paste that range into `Sheet3`.

Upon running the code each time `UsedRange` will be paste into `Sheet3` from first empty Row.

**For Example:** There are 5 rows (1st Row will always be Header) in the `Sheet1` with data i will press run the code will copy and paste the data into `Sheet3` `Row2` (1st Row will always be Header).

So now the `Sheet3` has data till `Row5` I will press the run button again then data will be pasted from `Row6`.

Upon pressing button each time data will be paste accordingly. I got a code online and tried to edit it but its not working as i want.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Code.

```
Sub usedrange()

    Dim ws1         As Worksheet
    Dim ws2         As Worksheet
    Dim source      As Range
    Dim target      As Range
    Dim lastColumn  As Long

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("NewSheet")
    Set ws2 = Sheet3

    With ws2
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(1)) > 0 Then
            lastrow = lastrow + 1
        End If
    End With

    Set source = ws1.usedrange.Offset(1)
    Set target = ws2.Cells(, lastrow)

    source.Copy Destination:=target
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Used Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyUsedRange()

    Dim ws1         As Worksheet
    Dim ws2         As Worksheet
    Dim Source      As Range
    Dim Target      As Range
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    
    ' Code names
    Set ws1 = Sheet1
    Set ws2 = Sheet3
    ' Tab Names
    'Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    
    With ws1.UsedRange
        Set Source = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    With ws2
        Set Target = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
 
    Source.Copy Target

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @VBasic2008 i have been overwhelmed by seeing the response of experts. You guys are great. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Code is self explanatory

```
Public Sub CopyUsedRange()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sourceSheetName")
    
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("targetSheetName")

    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.UsedRange.Resize(sourceSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, sourceSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1)
    
    Dim targetLastRow As Long
    targetLastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("A" & targetLastRow + 1)
    
    sourceRange.Copy targetRange
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub usedrange()

    Dim ws1         As Worksheet
    Dim ws2         As Worksheet
    Dim source      As Range
    Dim target      As Range
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("NewSheet")
    Set ws2 = Sheet3
    
    With ws1
        r = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        c = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        Set rngDB = .Range("a1", .Cells(r, c))
    End With
    Set source = rngDB.Offset(1)
    vDB = source
    Set target = ws2.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)

    target.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

End Sub
```

Comment: @Mento, You deserve answers from many people. You are good at asking questions, and you respond immediately to the questioner. good.

Comment: Thank you @Dy.Lee